# Why does changing from targeting a class to a type in CSS cause different results?

Tags: html, css

I thought I would be clever and remove my "author" class from the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/cMYEH/3/ and replace it with "cite" in the CSS, with an eye on reducing the size of the HTML.

The only element that has the "author" class applied to it are the "cite" elements. So it should work exactly the same, right? But when I changed the CSS from this:

```css
.author {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: White;
    width: 160px;
}
```

...to this:

```css
cite {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: White;
    width: 160px;
}
```

...the name no longer displays -- it's as if it is "painted in black." Why would the color (White) not be applied?

### UPDATE

Dang it! I messed up again...Actually, I miswrote: it was/is the "*title*" class that was inside the "cite" element, not author - hence causing all this confusion!... http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/cMYEH/5/

Comment: taldonn: .cite is a class name <cite> is an HTML5 tag

Comment: @taldonn `<cite>` is an element

Comment: from what I see within your jsFiddle you are using a *class author* on some **div elements**. can't find a cite element using author class! (eg: `<div id="prizeArtist" class="author">`)

Comment: @xec Thanks. I learn something new every day.

Comment: @Diodeus: It's not even new to HTML5.

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz the question is he removed the author class, it's what the question is about

Comment: @Huangism see question text: "only element that has the "author" class applied to it are the "cite" elements" thats not correct, at least i can't find a cite tag with an author class - am i missing something?

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz you are misunderstanding it, he had .author on all cite elements before, then he removed the class and applied the styles to the cite element instead to save file size. And now he is wondering why the cite elements which had the .author class are not displaying the same as before. He still has a few .authors on divs now so the question is kind of confusing but just ignore those for now

Comment: If this question was worded better, we probably would of had a lot more answers

Comment: The biggest issue here is cite is not defined at all in the css lol

Comment: Actually, I miswrote: it was/is the "title" class that was inside the "cite" element, not author - hence causing all this confusion!

Comment: If you use Chrome and inspect element you will see where is what css setting comming from, and what overrides what.

Comment: @ClayShannon Update your question and put an edit so people knows what's going on

Comment: BTW, I've got my wife to calling me "The OP" at home now, as that is how I am referred to more than any other way, and I've gotten accustomed to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<cite>` element has a class `title` with associated styles, which is overriding it, because *class selectors are more specific than element selectors*.

This is a nice resource on the topic: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

---

### update

Adding some examples to clarify;

#### css

```css
.title {
    color: blue;
}

/* will override .title because they have same specificity but is defined later */
.author { 
    color: red;
}

/* will not override any class selector even when defined last*/
cite {
    color: green;
}
```

#### html

```html
<cite class="title">will be blue, not green</cite>
<cite class="title author">will be red, see comment in css</cite><br>
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/K7r56/

Comment: the .author class was removed from all cite elements and now OP is targeting using cite because he wants to save a few bytes. Although there are still elements with author but they are not cite.

Comment: @BoltClock You are correct, but I still believe this is what's causing the issue. (There are no `cite` selectors in the demo, only the question). It would be easier to answer if it was clear what he wanted it to look like, though...

Comment: People, this question is not about .author class. He has defined styles on cite, he is asking why it is not displaying like that. He had author class on cite before and it was fine but now he moved those styles to cite and deleted author class. So the answer I believe is correct, the question sounds confusing because he still have .author class on some divs

Comment: I just notice the OP probably forgot to add the cite css block to the fiddle

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add the cite css block into the fiddle or forgot to change .author to cite

http://jsfiddle.net/cMYEH/4/

```css
cite {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: White;
    width: 160px;
}
```

If this does not look right then refer to xec's answer

Comment: I just have to give you +1 for first class detective work leading to solving the confusion! :)

Comment: Thank you, this whole question has been a debacle, half of the people understood it a different way and at the end, it was posted wrong lol